# How can I initialize a list of c() in R?

Tags: r

Like `list(c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),       c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c(),c())`

I tried `list(rep(c(),21))`, but that does not really work. I failed using `rbind` as well.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

We can place the `c()` in a `list` and then use `rep`

```
rep(list(c()), 21)
```

Or with `replicate`

```
replicate(21, c())
```

Or as @joran commented

```
vector("list",21)
```

Comment: Why not just `vector("list",21)`

Answer (score 1):

> Atomic vectors are always flat, even if you nest c()’s: ([Hadley: Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#vectors))

So it does not make sense to make a list of vector. But it will make sense as  has [@joran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324364/joran) suggested to make a vector of list.

Comment: You cannot make a vector of vectors, this is why it makes sense to make a list of vectors